# c# generic interface impossible to implement

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

Inside a library I am developing, I need multiple unrelated types to provide values for (possibly many) "tags". Each tag has an associated type of value, and is represented as a (singleton) class inheriting the following generic base:

```
public abstract class Tag<TTag,TValue>
  where TTag: Tag<TTag,TValue>
{
}
```

(the type parameter `TTag` employs the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern).

I want provide an interface `IProvider<TTag>`, which would mark classes that can provide values for a specific tag. Ideally, the interface would look like this:

```
public interface IProvider<TTag>
{
  TValue GetValue<TValue>(Tag<TTag,TValue> tag);
}
```

This would allow the type of value to be deduced from the supplied tag
(in case a type is a provider for multiple tags).
Unfortunately, using the class `Tag<TTag,TValue>` requires he constraint
`TTag: Tag<TTag,TValue>`, which cannot be specified on this method, as its only generic parameter is `TValue`. I tried doing this instead:

```
public interface IProvider<TTag>
{
  TValue GetValue<TTag2,TValue>(Tag<TTag2,TValue> tag)
    where TTag2: Tag<TTag2,TValue>, TTag;
}
```

My intention was that, if `TTag` is a tag class inheriting `Tag<TTag,TValue>`,
the only way for `TTag2` to meet these constraints is to be equal to `TTag`.
The interface written this way compiles correctly. However, coming with an implementation causes problems:

```
public struct Data<TTag,TValue> : IProvider<TTag>
  where TTag: Tag<TTag,TValue>
{
  public TValue Value;

  public TValue2 GetValue<TTag2,TValue2>(Tag<TTag2,TValue2> tag)
    where TTag2: Tag<TTag2,TValue2>, TTag
  {
    return (TValue2) Value;
  }
}
```

The above fails to compile with error CS0455, as the type `TTag2` inherits two unrelated class constraints `Tag<TTag2,TValue2>` and `Tag<TTag,TValue>` (the language rules do not notice the "obvious" fact that these have to be equal). Making the method implement the interface explicitly... crashes the compiler (mono 3.2.8).

After this long introduction, here comes my question: is it possible to come up with an implementable definition of `IProvider<TTag>` without sacrificing any of the (hopefully intuitively clear by now) constraints? If not, can you suggest a different type hierarchy for the original scenario? Thanks!

P.S. Let me rule out any implementations which mention the tag's value type as a generic parameter of `IProvider` - the actual value types are complex enough, so that the inability to infer them completely kills making use of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Where this structure falls over, as far as I can see as quick glance, is in the `Data` struct where you are saying that field `TValue Value` is being returned as `TValue2` in the `GetValue` method. It's not the same type.

So the only thing that I could come up with to make this work is to do this:

```
public abstract class Tag<TTag, TValue>
    where TTag: Tag<TTag,TValue>
{
}

public interface IProvider<TTag, TValue>
    where TTag: Tag<TTag,TValue>
{
    TValue GetValue(TTag tag);
}

public struct Data<TTag, TValue> : IProvider<TTag, TValue>
    where TTag: Tag<TTag, TValue>
{
    public TValue Value;

    public TValue GetValue(TTag tag)
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

But this conflicts with your requirement in your question.

This gets your closer:

```
public interface IProvider<TTag>
{
    TValue GetValue<T, TValue>(T tag) where T : Tag<T, TValue>;
}

public struct Data<TTag, TValue> : IProvider<TTag>
{
    public TValue Value;

    public TV GetValue<T, TV>(T tag) where T : Tag<T, TV>
    {
        return (TV)(object)Value;
    }
}
```

But again the problem here is the line `return (TV)(object)Value;` - You can't convert the value of `TValue` to `TV` because the whole point of this code was to leave the return type of the `GetValue` method free. But that's impossible to do.

You have to have the `TValue` parameter on the `IProvider` interface.

Comment: (Regarding the first suggested solution) The problem is not in the body of `GetValue` (if all generic constraints were satisfied, the cast would always succeed, and besides, it is not a compile-time issue) -- its mere existence causes the compiler error. What you suggest was actually my first approach -- it works but, for the reasons I stated, is useless.

Comment: @GrzegorzHerman - If the cast always succeeds then the `TValue` type on the `GetValue` method isn't free at all so you can go back to the first part of my solution. But you say that's impossible. I think you are stuck.

Comment: Your second code allows the same `GetValue` method to possibly implement multiple `IProvider<>` interfaces, which is wrong, as the values for different tags (even if of the same type) will usually differ. Even worse, implementing a single `IProvider<>` allows asking for a value of any tag, which will only fail at runtime!